# How to check user is Admin or not in laravel blade view

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have

User table like

```
+==============+
|     User     |
+==============+
|      id      |
+--------------+
|   firstname  |
+--------------+
|    lastname  |
+--------------+
|     email    |
+--------------+
|   password   |
+--------------+
```

and my roles table

```
+==============+
|     Roles    |
+==============+
|      id      |
+--------------+
|     name     |
+--------------+
```

and my role_user table is

```
+=============+
|  role_user  |
+=============+
|   user_id   |
+-------------+
|   role_id   |
+-------------+
```

How can I check current logged user is admin or normal user?

Comment: You need to start by creating a relationship between the tables or models. Example User hasOne RoleUser etc

Comment: Do you have the many-to-many relation already defined between user and role models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Role.php**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    /**
     * A role can have many users.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function users() {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

}
```

Then you can add this to **User model**:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    foreach ($this->roles()->get() as $role)
    {
        if ($role->name == 'Admin')
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@if(Auth::check())
    @if (Auth::user()->isAdmin())
        <h2>Admin user enter code here<h2>
    @endif
@endif
```

Answer (score 26):

You need to add `roles` relationship in your `User` model like so:

```
public function roles() 
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(App\Role::class);
}
```

and now you need to create `isAdmin` user like so:

```
public function isAdmin() 
{
   return in_array(1, $this->roles()->pluck('role_id')->all());
}
```

As `1` you put id of your admin role. Of course it could be also defined in other way, but everything depends on how this will be used.

It could be also defined this way:

```
public function isAdmin() 
{
   return $this->roles()->where('role_id', 1)->first();
}
```

and now in your Blade you can do:

```
@if (auth()->check())
   @if (auth()->user()->isAdmin())
      Hello Admin
   @else
      Hello standard user
   @endif
@endif
```

Comment: Very simple and nice answer. I also tried like this answer it worked. Thank you @MarcinNabialek

Comment: `isAdmin()` should be written in the either Model or Controller ?

Comment: @stack It should be addded to `User` model

Comment: I am getting an error `Class 'App\App\Role' not found` any ideas?

Comment: @aronccs It's because your Modal is already in the namespace of `App`, so if you type in `App\Role` in the `App` namespace, it will look for the `App\App\Role` class.  Laravel, by default (when you create it with artisan commands) will place your modal in the `App` namespace.

Answer (score 8):

It's not an [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) for this simple functionality you don't even need a database table `roles` you can add extra `tinyInteger` `status` column and add numbers for example:

- 0 = Disabled
- 1 = Visitor
- 2 = Admin.

To make it functional add following code to your `User.php`.

```
public function isDisabled ()
{
    return $this->statusCheck();
}

public function isVisitor ()
{
    return $this->statusCheck(1);
}

public function isAdmin ()
{
    return $this->statusCheck(2);
}

protected function statusCheck ($status = 0)
{
    return $this->status === $status ? true : false;
}
```

To check in `blade` template you can add

```
@if(Auth::user()->isDisabled())
    You are not Active
@elseif(Auth::user()->isVisitor())
    Welcome to example.com
@elseif(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
    Welcome Admin
@endif
```

Moreover you can make blade custom directives, paste this code to your `app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php` in `boot()` method.

```
// Blade custom directives for isAdmin

    Blade::directive('isAdmin', function() {
        return "<?php if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()): ?>";
    });

    Blade::directive('endisAdmin', function() {
        return "<?php endif; ?>";
    });

// Blade custom directives for isVisitor

    Blade::directive('isVisitor', function() {
        return "<?php if(Auth::user()->isVisitor()): ?>";
    });

    Blade::directive('endisVisitor', function() {
        return "<?php endif; ?>";
    });

// Blade custom directives for isDisabled

    Blade::directive('isDisabled', function() {
        return "<?php if(Auth::user()->isDisabled()): ?>";
    });

    Blade::directive('endisDisabled', function() {
        return "<?php endif; ?>";
    });
```

To call this you use need to write following lines in your `blade view`

```
@isAdmin()
     Welcome Admin
@endisAdmin

@isVisitor()
     Welcome to example.com
@endisVisitor

@isDisabled()
     Your are not active
@endisDisabled
```

In short laravel provides you a number of ways to solve a problem, it just depend on your need and application structure.

Answer (score 1):

the methods shared works. the problem is if you have to check more than once per page, it hits the database that many times. for instance, let's say you have a navigation with 8 links. the first, fourth, and seventh links should only be visible by admin only. that query will hit your database 3x. maybe i'm just anal but it's a duplicated request.

i'm trying to find another way to store a variable that loads once in the view/template so that every time i need to check if it's an admin, i check the variable and not hit the database every time. i've done it via controller -> view, but not just view alone in a template. i'm thinking of creating a helper method and returning an object to be checked once per page load.

Answer (score -3):

So you have some field isAdmin if it is 1 for example user is admin if not it is not. When user is loged check with `(Auth::user()->isAdmin == 1)` then user is admin else it is not

with `Auth::user()->` u can check any field from user table of current logged user.

Best Regards

Comment: do i need wride down any method for this ?

Comment: No laravel have Auth method, I asume u made login etc... You can check anything with Auth::user()->, did you use laravels user model?

Comment: @MasterSith your solution can never work without creating a model relationships between the tables

Comment: I asumed he used user model that laravel provides from start.