# How to check user is Admin in laravel blade view without calling DB multiple times

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How to check if user is Admin or not in laravel blade view without calling DB multiple times?
Is there a way how to pass it in generic way to all views?

I have relationships, middleware and all defined. This is DB structure:

`user` table:

- id
- email
- name

`role` table:

- id
- name

`user_role` table:

- id
- user_id
- role_id

Note: DB structure has to be like that, I dont want to have to have IsAdmin flag on user table as I am not planning to add new column everytime new role is added.

Currently what I am doing in views is pretty basic:

View:

```html
@if(auth()->user()->IsAdministrator()))
    ..
@endif
```

User model:

```
public function isAdministator() 
{
   return $this->roles()->where('role_id', 1)->exists();
}
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

Which is fine and it is working, but the problem is, when I need to do this multiple times on the page:

- to show Edit button only to Admins
- to make Delete button visible only to Admins
- in navigation menu, to show specific menu items only for Admins

Everytime I am checking for IsAdministrator(), it is making a DB query for same thing.

1. I was thinking about passing this from Controller, but to all Controllers?
2. I also thought to add constructor to base controller: Controller.php but getting NULL for auth()->user()
3. Perhaps using below, but it is not working as I am getting NULL as well, when I am trying to pass $IsAdmin = auth()-user()-IsAdministrator() https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Is there good practice on this?

Note 2: same question was asked by user w1n78, but it was lost in between other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47082188/8009914

Comment: you haven't showed what this `isAdministrator` method is doing

Comment: ok, I didnt think it is needed, because it is what you can see everywhere. post edited.

Comment: please add it to your question as that is the method that is causing your query .... you don't have to be querying the `roles` relationship every time that method is called, you could have that relation loaded and search the collection of roles to see if the one you are looking for exists

Comment: One quick fix is change `->first` to `->exists`, so you just return a boolean instead of a model, but I doubt that will fix anything at all... (`return $this->roles()->where('role_id', 1)->exists();`

Comment: sure, exists(). anyway still same question, of how to call DB only once when it is multiple times in view

Comment: I would say you could have sort of singleton and let it have a state, so the first time does a request, second time it will have a value, so you it will give you the value back. Another solution was posted by @mrhn and is correct

Answer (score 2):

In Eloquent in Laravel, accessing query builders as so `$this->roles()` will always create an SQL query to the database when that code is called.

If you utilize the relationship loading that Eloquent automatically does, it will not perform multiple queries.

```
// one query
$this->roles->where('role_id', 1)->first();
$this->roles->where('role_id', 1)->first();
$this->roles->where('role_id', 1)->first();

// three queries
$this->roles()->where('role_id', 1)->first();
$this->roles()->where('role_id', 1)->first();
$this->roles()->where('role_id', 1)->first();
```

The only downside is with the query builder you get the power of SQL functions. With the eloquent relationship approach you are limited to the [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections) class representing an array of relationship models in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `auth()->user() -> ...` in your view multiple times, define a variable and pass it to your views:

```php
$user = auth()->user();

return view('...', ['user' => $user]);
```

*Note: This can be done in a Controller to return to a Single view, or in [`View Composer`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#view-composers) for all views, etc.*

This will allow you to call `$user->isAdministrator()` in your views. Currently, this is the same as your existing code, but we can now make this more performant, since the User **and it's relationships** can be loaded into a variable.

First, load your `roles` relationship:

```php
$user = auth()->user();

$user->load('roles');

return view('...', ['user' => $user]);
```

Now, `$user->roles` can be accessed **without needing an additional query**. As pointed out correctly by mrhn, `$user->roles()` will **ALWAYS** execute a new query, regardless if the Relationship has been loaded or not.

In your `isAdministrator()` method, adjust your code:

```php
public function isAdministrator() {
  if (!$this->relationLoaded('roles')) { 
    throw new Exception('Roles relationship not loaded');
    // Or return `false`, etc.; up to you on how to handle this
  }

  return $this->roles->first(function ($role) { 
    return $role->id === 1;
  });

  // https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-first
  // `->first()` will return a `Role` instance, or `null`, which is "truthy" enough

  // Or, tack on `? true : false`, or cast to `(bool)`, etc.

  // return $this->roles->first(function ($role) { 
  //   return $role->id === 1;
  // }) ? true : false;

  // return (bool)$this->roles->first(function ($role) { 
  //   return $role->id === 1;
  // });
}
```

Now, in your view, check your method via:

```php
@if($user->isAdministrator())
  // Handles `true` or `false` from method, without having to call any additional queries
@endif
```

If all is done properly, you should be able to call `$user->isAdministrator()`, and/or other `->is{Whatever}()` methods multiple times without trigging any additional queries.

Sidenote, in later versions of Laravel, you can force this behaviour by triggering an Exception when you try to access a relationship that isn't loaded:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#preventing-lazy-loading

If you included that code, you would be able to remove the `if (!$this->relationLoaded('role')) { ... }` section of your `isAdministrator()` method, as it would be handled by the Application globally.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [`spatie/once`](https://github.com/spatie/once) to ensure the lookup only occurs once during a request.

```php
function isAdministrator(): bool
{
    return once(fn () => $this->roles()->where('role_id', 1)->exists());
}
```

A policy might also be a good place for this, but I don't think it provides any caching behaviour like you're after either. If you're using Laravel Nova `once` is already installed for you